# RxJs - Jasmine marbles forkJoin operator test

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, jasmine-marbles

Here is forkJoin operator jasmine marble test:

```
it('test1', () => {

 const a = cold('---a|', { a: 1 });
 const b = cold('---b|', { b: 2 });

 const observable = forkJoin(
   a,
   b
 );

 const expected = cold('---21');
 expect(observable).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

The test produces the following errors:

```
Expected $[0].frame = 40 to equal 30.
Expected $[0].notification.value = [ 1, 2 ] to equal '2'.
Expected $[1].frame = 40 to equal 50.
Expected $[1].notification.kind = 'C' to equal 'N'.
Expected $[1].notification.value = undefined to equal '1'.
Expected $[1].notification.hasValue = false to equal true.
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's `cold` ? Some custom operator ? Never have I seen it.

Comment: Anyway, please provide a [mcve] of your issue

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md#time-progression-syntax...it is from rxjs-marble-testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First `---21` will wait three frames, then emit `'2'` and then emit `'1`.  Fork join is not a `merge` it will emit once, and it will emit `[1, 2]`.

Alphanumeric marbles advance one frame when they emit.  So both `a` and `b` will complete at frame 4.  The forkJoin will then resolve emit.  The forkJoin will then immediately complete (also at frame 4).

So the errors you are getting:

`Expected $[0].frame = 40 to equal 30.` The first item emitted from the fork-join is at time 4 (because a and b complete at time 4) not at time 3.

`Expected $[0].notification.value = [ 1, 2 ] to equal '2'.` The value emitted is `[1, 2]` and not `'2'` as described above.

```
Expected $[1].frame = 40 to equal 50.
Expected $[1].notification.kind = 'C' to equal 'N'.
Expected $[1].notification.value = undefined to equal '1'.
Expected $[1].notification.hasValue = false to equal true.
```

You are expecting a `'1'` at time 5.  It is getting a `complete` at time 4.

So you probably want...

```
const expected = cold('----(a|)', { a: [1, 2] });
expect(observable).toBeObservable(expected);
```